# Does "I don't know" have a question mark after know?

Tags: punctuation

Does"I don't know" have a question mark after know? I'm writing a story so that's why I am asking.

Comment: I don't know?..

Comment: You mean you don't know whether or not you don't know?

Comment: hah. Funny, but still this can be a tough question.

Comment: Basically, are you asking a question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's no need to use a question mark if you are just declaring that you don't know.

But you can use a question mark if you are doubtful about not knowing; sometimes people ask "I don't know" like a question when they think they should know about whatever the topic of that conversation is. It's similar to when someone says "I think so" in a tone that conveys he/she is unsure. For instance:

Person: Was there homework last night?

Someone: I think so?

Comment: Some people talk all the time as though every sentence ends in a question mark.

Comment: @NigelJ I think so too?

Comment: @NVZ It's called a rhetorical accent ?